# Get raw value of a property in a query containing $select

Tags: odata

Is there a way to get the raw value of the "Name" property in the [following query](http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Genres?%24select=Name&%24filter=Name%20eq%20%2720th%20Century%20Period%20Pieces%27)

I have tried appending "/$value" at the end but that does not work.

Here is another example to retrieve the raw value of the "[Synopsis](http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Titles?%24filter=startswith%28Name,%27Die%27%29&%24top=1&%24select=Synopsis)" property of a movie but all I can get to is the full xml payload and not the raw synopsis data.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this mainly because $value can only work on a single result, but both queries you showed can return multiple results (OData doesn't understand that the filter is on the key property and thus it will only ever return a single result).

The only way to get the raw value is to directly navigate to the single result, so if you know the ID of entity (which in the case of the first query is known, it's the value of the Name property), you can use this instead:
http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Genres('20th%20Century%20Period%20Pieces')
This returns a single result (even in the model) and thus you can do:
http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Genres('20th%20Century%20Period%20Pieces')/Name/$value
(Although I'm not sure why you would do that since you already know the name anyway :-))

In the second query you don't know the key property values, so you would have to get those first to be able to navigate to the Title in question directly, then you can get to the synopsis just like above. In this case the $top=1 doesn't really mean take the single result (the first one), it just means take "n" results, where n happens to be 1. In the model world the $top=1 still returns potentially multiple results (even though in this case it really returns only 1 ever).